# Custom label from using separate array in Chart JS

Tags: jquery, charts, tooltip, chart.js

In my project, I am using `Chart.JS` to show the line chart.

Right now the tooltip in the  graph showing like

> Date: 01/02/2016
>
> Price: 50

These data getting from two arrays. 
**But I need to show one more data below the price. So the tooltip will be like**

> Date: 01/02/2016
>
> Price: 50
>
> Shop: Shop Name

How can I achieve this in `Chart JS`? Or is it possible with some other chart? Please help. My sample code to generate the graph is

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
    labels: data.day,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Price Change',
        data: data.price,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0, 183, 255,0.4)",
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)",
    }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                    return 'Price: '+tooltipItems.yLabel;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

**In the above code `data.price` is storing the price array. I need to pass the store details with it and show it in the tooltip.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can storing your tooltips items in an array, and return back, it will show on the tooltips label.

for example:

```
callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var firstTooltip = "toolTipsIdx: " + tooltipItem.index;
        var otherTooltip = "Ylabel value: " + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        var tooltip = [firstTooltip, otherTooltip]; //storing all the value here
        return tooltip; //return Array back to function to show out
    }
}
```